# Fail to read double value after WindowsAzure.Storage package updated

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am running a webapp - using WindowsAzure.Storage 7.2.0 - for reading a lot of data in table storage. I upgraded now the nuget package to WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3 and now I have problems to read correctly double values, which are stored in the storage.

The data are inserted into the table storage by an ASA Job, which has not changed for a couple of months, and and I can see the values in the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer eg. -0.4 for a small negative decimal.

But the read operation is fetching -4.
I made some tests with EntityResolver but I found no working solution. 
Does someone have an idea, what has changed and how to solve this problem?
Here is the code snippet which I am using but is not working

```
            TableQuery<MeasurandRealTime> query = new TableQuery<MeasurandRealTime>().Where(filter);

        //********************************** only for tests - not working *********************************

        NumberFormatInfo decimalProvider = new NumberFormatInfo();
        decimalProvider.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
        EntityResolver<MeasurandRealTime> measurandResolver = (PartitionKey, RowKey, Timestamp, props, Etag) =>
        {
            MeasurandRealTime entity = new MeasurandRealTime();
            entity.PartitionKey = PartitionKey;
            entity.RowKey = RowKey;
            entity.Timestamp = Timestamp;
            entity.ETag = Etag;
            entity.vs = props.ContainsKey("vs") ? props["vs"].StringValue : null;
            entity.r = props.ContainsKey("r") ? props["r"].Int32Value : null;
            entity.s = props.ContainsKey("s") ? props["s"].Int32Value : null;
            if (props.ContainsKey("v")) entity.v = props["v"].DoubleValue;
            else entity.v = null;
            entity.cts = DateTime.Parse(props["cts"].DateTime.ToString(), null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
            entity.ctse = (long)props["ctse"].Int64Value;

            return entity;
        };
        //**************************************************************************************************/

        List < MeasurandRealTime> resultList = new List<MeasurandRealTime>(measurandCount);

        TableContinuationToken token = null;
        do
        {
            //TableQuerySegment<MeasurandRealTime> queryResult = await _cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token);
            TableQuerySegment<MeasurandRealTime> queryResult = await _cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, measurandResolver, token);
            token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
            resultList.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
        } while (token != null);
```

With the nuget package WindowsAzure.Storage 7.2.0, I didn't use the EntityResolver and the code was working without it (look at commented line)

Any hints for solving this problem are appreciated.

Best regards Michael

Comment: Not able to reproduce it on my side. Can you confirm `-4` is from the same entity which is set `-0.4`?

Comment: I am watching this value with the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, this tool shows  -0.4 ( not -4)

Comment: I see, my data is inserted directly in Storage Explorer instead of ASA job but I see the double value is retrieved correctly using same `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync`. What's the type of `entity.v`, double?

Comment: Hello, I have fixed the problem. In the statrup code of my webapp there was set

`CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient(); 
cloudTableClient.DefaultRequestOptions.PayloadFormat = TablePayloadFormat.JsonNoMetadata;`


This made the problem, In the meantime I have found a github issue 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/690 explaining the same issue

Comment: Great job! Could you post that as an answer for more people to refer?